# How can I add a new Item to fabric?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I'm trying to code a mod, which adds a new Item to the game and I'm following a tutorial on youtube. I also looked everything up on the fabric website, but the code doesn't work.

Here is the code I used. It is from the fabric wiki:

```java
public static final Item CUSTOM_ITEM = new Item(new FabricItemSettings().group(ItemGroup.MISC));
 
@Override
public void onInitialize() {
Registry.register(Registry.ITEM, new Identifier("tutorial", "custom_item"), CUSTOM_ITEM);
}
```

Somehow in my library the .group() function doesn't exist and that's the same with other functions.

Do I have to download something or how can I fix this?

I tried adding a new Item to my mod, but it didn't work.

Comment: Which Minecraft version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.group` method was removed in version 1.19.3

To add your item to an item group, you must use the `ItemGroupEvents.modifyEntriesEvent(ItemGroup group)` event provided by Fabric API.

In your case, you'll need to store the result of the `Registry.register` method in the `CUSTOM_ITEM` field if you want to pass it to the `modifyEntries` event:

```java
public static final Item CUSTOM_ITEM = Registry.register(Registry.ITEM, new Identifier("tutorial", "custom_item"), new Item(new FabricItemSettings()));

public void onInitialize() {
   ItemGroupEvents.modifyEntriesEvent(ItemGroup.MISC).register(itemGroup -> 
   {
      // Add the custom item to the MISC item group.
      itemGroup.add(CUSTOM_ITEM);
   });
}
```

---

You can read more about creating custom items here:

- https://fabric.mineblock11.dev/items/creating-first-item
- https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:items